# ReSharper right toolbar is not shown

Tags: resharper, toolbar, visibility

I have Resharper 9.0.0.0 on VisualStudio 2010.
I've changed few settings and thenceforth I couldn't see realtime errors anymore.
Finally I found the way to show the VS editor errors,
but I couldn't find the way to show the right toolbar of ReSharper
(that shows errors and suggestions) back.
Does anyone can guid me?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you need to go to *ReSharper > Options > Code Inspection > Settings* and turn *Enable code analysis* on again.